# How PostgreSQL function uses \set variables defined out of the function

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing a function which may use some constant variables quite often, so I plan to define them above the function, just like this:

```
\set MAX      10.0
\set MIDDLE   5.0
\set LOW      3.0
\set MIN      1.0
\set RATING_MAX  5   
\set RATING_MIN  0

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_rating() RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    power_5hr double precision;
    rating integer;
BEGIN
IF power_5hr >= :MAX THEN 
    rating := :RATING_MAX;
-- .... others
END IF;
RETURN rating;

END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But I got an error: **syntax error at or near ":"**
which indicates that I cannot use :MAX this way. And if I change :MAX to 10.0, it works.

Could you share what I should do to achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: The PostgreSQL database server doesn't have access to local variables in your database client (psql in this case). Use input-variables for your function.

Comment: You should declare those as parameters to the function.

Comment: I checked the document, but did not find any clue about how to share data in and out of the function, also I had several try, but failed, so I think both you are right, and I have to make them input parameters. Thanks Frank and  a_horse_with_no_name.